# Volume between sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2$ and paraboloid $z= x^2+y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

Express the volume of region $D$ upper bounded by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ and the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$.

a- Cartesian Coordinates

b- Cylindrical Surface

c- Spherical coordinates

If you help me to write the integral for a, b and c ; I can solve this integral but I made something wrong. Results are different but I don't know which result is correct.

Comment: Show your drawings.

Comment: sure this is my solution steps https://pasteboard.co/JbO3qLdM.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Now, from drawing the curves, it can be seen that the region is lower bounded by the parabola, and upper bounded by the sphere. The plane of intersection is $z = 1$, which can be obtained from solving the quadratic $z^2 + z - 2 = 0$

Now, for the region below the intersection plane

$$V_1 = \int\int\int dV$$

With $0 \leq z \leq 1$, $-\sqrt{z} \leq y \leq \sqrt{z}$, $-\sqrt{z-y^2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{z-y^2}$

Hence

$$V_1 = \int_0^1 \left(\int_{-\sqrt {z}} ^ {\sqrt z}\left(\int_{-\sqrt{z-y^2}}^{\sqrt{z-y^2}}dx\right)dy\right)dz$$

The portion above the plane of intersection will be bounded by the sphere, so take the limits accordingly

Comment: thanks really for your helping , which method is this called? (spherical or Cartesian) I couldn't enter the online course due to Corona days.

Comment: This would be cartesian

Comment: I recommend looking at this once https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element

Comment: I really thanks again. I'm a student at the first year. Maths is really universe. What I want to ask simply, without drawing, if we apply the same method by finding intersection of the value z then finding the boundaries, can we find true result?